# Using resttemplate for external API calls - performance

Tags: java, performance, rest, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am a jr.dev and have worked with Spring Boot in different projects, mainly for creating server/client where client sends some stuff to a server, the server then calls external API's to reflect changes on the clients side.

In the future I will be involved in creating a backend for a administration portal. On this portal, there might be up to ~100 users making changes at the same time. With the aformentioned server/client systems, updates were infrequent so performance was not prioritized, however, if 100 users are on this administration portal at the same time the user experience may be poor.

Structure of what I am building:

Client (browser) CRUD -> my backend -> 1-3 external API calls to locally hosted services.

And this is where my lack of Spring's Resttemplate is lacking. If 10 users make a request roughly at the same time, the RESTcontroller will try to execute the corresponding code for the 10 requests at the same time, BUT since the code is using Resttemplate to do external API calls, will each RESTcontroller "thread" have to wait for their turn because Resttemplate is synchronous? - In turn making the last RESTcontroller request having to wait for possibly 10-30 Resttemplate calls to the external API, which take roughly 30ms each.

Is there a better way to handle it? So that each request to the restcontroller can contact the external API without having to wait for another thread to free up Resttemplate?

I might be talking gibberish, I find it's very hard to google specific questions about Spring/RESTcontroller/Resttemplate's structure, whether they are asynchronous/synchronous etc..

Comment: you can use [Async RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#rest-client-access) or [WebClient](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#spring-webflux)